# Module named '_auto_generated_ear_' failed to deploy on Weblogic 10.3.5

Tags: eclipse, weblogic-10.x, icefaces-3

I am getting Module named '_auto_generated_ear_' failed to deploy this error while deploying my ICEFACES 3 sample project.
I am using Eclipse Helios and Weblogic 10.3.5

Exception Stack trace-
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Module named '_auto_generated_ear_' failed to deploy. See Error Log view for more detail.
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.deployAutoGenerateEarApplication(WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.java:807)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishWeblogicModules(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:1438)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishToServer(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:898)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishOnce(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:686)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publish(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:539)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Server.java:3087)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Server.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Contains: Deployment failed. See Error Log view for more detail.

java.lang.Exception: Exception received from deployment driver. See Error Log view for more detail.
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.DeploymentProgressListener.watch(DeploymentProgressListener.java:190)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.deployAutoGenerateEarApplication(WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.java:788)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishWeblogicModules(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:1438)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishToServer(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:898)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishOnce(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:686)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publish(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:539)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Server.java:3087)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Server.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

Comment: I havent written any code...just made dynamic project with Iceface 3 and finished.When I tried to run the index.xhtml(by default created) file using weblogic I am getting this error.

Comment: It is just a blank project with default files.